# The trap door in a bar top the waitress uses

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, technical

Many bar tops have a hinged section of bartop that can be lifted for entry and egress of servers to the back of the bar. Anyone know the name of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question. After some research and the help of a reverse dictionary, I found the following possibilities:

- **bar/counter hatch**
- **counter door**
- **bar/counter flap**

> **bar flap** *noun*
>
> The part of a bar counter (typically at one of its short sides) which lifts upwards on a hinge to allow access behind the counter.

*Source: Oxford Dictionaries*

Answer (score -2):

The waitress stand
It is where the waitress/waiters drop off empty glasses and debris, they also pick up drinks and supplies for customers. They also submit customer tabs to the bartender at this corner of the bar. The hinged flap door allows bar backs to enter with tubs of ice, beer, supplies without having to "limbo" under the dropped flap door.

Comment: You seem to be answering a question about what the door is for and not what it is called.